# Optical Zoom from ARSession

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, avcapturesession

I am using ARSCNView and ARKit. How do I zoom the camera ? I tried changing the fov of the sceneview camera, but it's getting overridden by ARkit.

Is there a way to access the AVcapturesession and get the device from there ?

Comment: This is so weird, facing the same problem, haven't found any info on this so far...
Have you been able to resolve this?